# tabla externa no está en el formato esperado (external table is not in the expected format)

Tags: vb.net, excel

Buena tarde,

Estoy realizando una aplicación en **Vb.Net** el cual debe verificar un archivo **Excel** y su contenido, pero al intentar abrir el archivo envia el error ***"Tabla externa no está en el formato esperado (external table is not in the expected format)"***, ya he buscado en el foro, en la versión en ingles y todo lo que dice allí lo he intentado sin resultado positivo, esto no pasa con todos los archivos solo con un archivo en especifico, lo cual me genera duda, ya que yo puedo abrirlo normal con el **Excel** normal pero con la aplicación genera este error, el archivo tiene una extención `.XLS`, asi mismo en mayuscula.

este es mi código, agradezco su ayuda:

```vb
Private Function validateXlsFile(ByVal path As String) As Boolean
    Private Excel03ConString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'"
    Private Excel07ConString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'"
    Private ExcelOnErrorConString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR={1}'"
    Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo(path)
    Dim header As String = "YES"
    Dim sheetName As String

    Try
        For Each fi As FileInfo In dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            If fi.Extension.ToLower = ".xls" Or fi.Extension.ToLower = ".xlsx" Then
                Dim conStr As String = String.Empty
                Select Case fi.Extension.ToLower
                    Case ".xls"
                        'Excel 97-03
                        conStr = String.Format(Excel03ConString, path + "\" + fi.Name, header)
                        Exit Select

                    Case ".xlsx"
                        'Excel 07
                        conStr = String.Format(Excel07ConString, path + "\" + fi.Name, header)
                        Exit Select
                End Select

                Try
                    'Get the name of the First Sheet.
                    Using con As New OleDbConnection(conStr)
                        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand
                            cmd.Connection = con
                            con.Open()
                            Dim dtExcelSchema As DataTable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
                            sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString()
                            con.Close()
                        End Using
                    End Using

                    'Read Data from the First Sheet.
                    Using con As New OleDbConnection(conStr)
                        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand
                            Using oda As New OleDbDataAdapter
                                Dim dt As New DataTable

                                dt.Clear()

                                cmd.CommandText = (Convert.ToString("SELECT * From [") & sheetName) + "]"
                                cmd.Connection = con
                                con.Open()
                                oda.SelectCommand = cmd
                                oda.Fill(dt)
                                con.Close()
                            End Using
                        End Using
                    End Using
                Catch ex As Exception
                    If ex.Message.Contains("External table is not in the expected format.") Then
                        conStr = String.Format(ExcelOnErrorConString, path + "\" + fi.Name, header)

                        'Get the name of the First Sheet.
                        Using con As New OleDbConnection(conStr)
                            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand
                                cmd.Connection = con
                                con.Open()
                                Dim dtExcelSchema As DataTable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
                                sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString()
                                con.Close()
                            End Using
                        End Using

                        'Read Data from the First Sheet.
                        Using con As New OleDbConnection(conStr)
                            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand
                                Using oda As New OleDbDataAdapter
                                    Dim dt As New DataTable

                                    dt.Clear()

                                    cmd.CommandText = (Convert.ToString("SELECT * From [") & sheetName) + "]"
                                    cmd.Connection = con
                                    con.Open()
                                    oda.SelectCommand = cmd
                                    oda.Fill(dt)
                                    con.Close()
                                End Using
                            End Using
                        End Using
                    Else
                        ErrorMessage = ex.Message
                        Return False
                    End If
                End Try

            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorMessage = ex.Message
        Return False
    End Try

    Return True

End Function
```

He intentado colocando el connection de varias maneras y nada:

```vb
Private ExcelOnErrorConString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR={1}'"
Private ExcelOnErrorConString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='HTML Import'"
```

Todo esto sin ningún resultado.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la versión de VB.NET que estás utilizando? Me interesa saber porque viendo el código parece que te acepta comentarios con la doble  barra, o tal vez ese sea el problema.

Comment: Estoy utilizando Vb.Net 2012 pero ese no es el problema, esos comentarios los puse asi aquí porque sino me ponia todo el código en Rojo XD, en realidad está comentado con el apostrofe, en si el código funciona, pero paasa con un archivo que no lo abre, sin embargo manualmente con el excel si lo abre

Comment: Ah, ya entiendo, no hay problema, ahora lo edito. Para ver cómo publicar los códigos puedes ver la ayuda para [Resaltado de sintaxis para código](http://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). Más información la encuentras en el [help]

Comment: Volviendo al problema del Excel, estuve tratando de reproducir el error alterando un archivo `.xls` de varias formas, pero en todos los casos se lee correctamente. Si puedes publicar el archivo que te está dando problemas, tal vez podamos encontrar una solución.

Comment: Es muy acertado el comentario que dice "Aprendiendo.NET" ya que por lo que se ve no estás haciendo nada mal Josue. Me quedaría con la idea de que el XLS está guardado en un formato de Excel raro, probaría abriendolo con un Excel y guardandolo en XLSX que es un formato de Excel más actual y ahi si probar si lo lee tu aplicación. A mi me ha pasado algo parecido trabajando con libreria Epplus y que no me leyera XLS.

Comment: Es correcto, la función funciona perfectamente, el XLS no lo puedo enviar ya que es información sensitiva de la empresa, y si yo lo abro en mi computadora con mi aplicación y lo guardo sin hacerle ningún tipo de cambio, la función lo lee correctamente, estoy claro que el error esta en ese archivo en especifico, no me quedara otra opción que decirle al cliente que arregle la manera en que esta guardando el archivo XLS, ya que con todos los demás no pasa este problema. Muchas gracias por la ayuda